# Matriz em linguagem C, erro zsh: abort

Tags: c, matriz

Estou tentando criar uma matriz para ler o nome de 5 alunos.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
    
int main(void){
    //Programa para calcular a média das notas de 5 alunos, sendo que cada aluno possui 3 notas.
   char nomes[5][30];
   float notas[5][4];
   float media[5];
   int cont1, cont2;
    
       
   //Leitura dos nomes e das notas de cada aluno.
   for(cont1 = 0;cont1 < 5; cont1++){
      scanf("%s", &nomes[cont1][30]);
   }
    
   //Imprimindo os nomes para testar
   for(cont2 = 0;cont2 < 5; cont2++){
      setbuf(stdin, 0);
      printf("\n%s", nomes[cont2]);
   }
    
   return(0);
}
```

O código está funcionando para ler os 5 nomes, porém ele exibe apenas 3 nomes e apresenta o erro `zsh: abort`. O que pode estar acontecendo?

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que os nomes não estão sendo lidos corretamente. Para ler uma *string* através do `scanf` você precisa passar o endereco do primeiro caracter da string. Veja um exemplo corrigido:

```
//Leitura dos nomes e das notas de cada aluno.
for(cont1 = 0; cont1 < 5; cont1++){
    scanf("%s", &nomes[cont1][0]);
}
```

Outro exemplo ainda mais simples:

```
//Leitura dos nomes e das notas de cada aluno.
for(cont1 = 0; cont1 < 5; cont1++){
   scanf("%s", nomes[cont1]);
}
```

Comment: No caso, isso que eu descrevi esta sendo considerado um vetor ou uma matriz?

Comment: @user196549 `char nomes[5][30]` é um vetor de vetores de `char`, ou seja é uma matriz de `char`. Basicamente matrizes são vetores que armazenam vetores.